# kContainer.newKieSession returns NULL in drools 7.37 version

Tags: drools

kContainer.newKieSession returns NULL on executing the below lines.

```
  KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
     KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
     KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
```

output is as follows :

kie session null
     kie service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl@3439f68d
     kie container org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl@dbd940d

Kmodule xml file detaisl :

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/7.37.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="Rules" packages="com.rule/">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules" type="stateless"/> 
    </kbase>
</kmodule>][1]
```

I have attached the eclipse structure and the pom xml file for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTlkb.jpg)

Comment: How are you running this? Via the commandline from the JAR created by Maven?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas..I am running from the eclipse IDE

Comment: So you're invoking a main method somewhere? You should confirm that the resources are correctly on your classpath. See if the same issue comes when running on the commandline.